# How to add text on video recording in Flutter?

Tags: video, flutter

I want to record a video along with current date and time on it in flutter. How to achieve this in flutter? I did google it, didn't find anything.

Comment: This is a tough one! One solution would be to introduce a post-processing step. With `ffmpeg`, on Android, setting an image/text overlay on the video file you recorded should be possible. The default camera plugin on Flutter doesn't allow for this.  `package:flutter_ffmpeg` should help.